# How can I test angularjs controllers that have been created with module().controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

For the purposes of this question, I've got an angular JS controller defined as such:

```
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'eric';
}
```

This tests fine using my normal node/karma/jasmine setup (testing in phantom, chrome, canary, firefox and safari):

```
describe('TestSquaredController', function(){
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('TestController', {$scope: scope});
  }));
  it('should be called eric', function() {
    expect(scope.name).toEqual('eric');
  });
});
```

However, when I use the the angular module.controller way of registering controllers, I get an error `Error: Argument 'TestController' is not a function, got undefined` when using the same test.

ie.

```
app.module('testAngularApp')
  .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 'eric';
  });
```

I can't seem to find anything related to this! Is there something else I should be initialising / doing in my tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test them the same exact way. Make sure you're loading the module with the controller in your tests via the [module function](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.module) in the ngMock module. Something like this:

```
beforeEach(module('testAngularApp'));
```

Comment: could you give a full example that uses this? Where is the module function defined? Is it supposed to be angular.module?

Comment: The documentation on the module function (linked in the answer above) has this: `NOTE: This function is also published on window for easy access.` which means it basically becomes a global function at that point. If you wanted to be explicit, the Usage part of that doc shows this: `angular.mock.module(fns);` so the line above would be `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('testAngularApp'));`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, getting the same error when running our Jasmine spec.

First we tried changing the order of includes as in the answer above, but this didn't fix it.

We then found that we had initialised our module in more than one place in the app, using the initialiser

```
var app = angular.module('testAngularApp', [])
```

at the top of all of our controller js files, whereas we only needed to initialise it once, and then include it at the top of our controller js files with

```
var app = angular.module('testAngularApp)
```

Perhaps you have also done something similar? Or failed to initialise it properly in the first case? Just a thought, in case you haven't managed to solve your problem.